# Are there certain JavaScript functions that aren't allowed?

Tags: javascript, 8

I am trying to use Google Publisher Tags for a site. I have the JavaScript and HTML files that work in a plain HTML document. However, if I use the same JavaScript file in Drupal, it doesn't run.

I can't find anything that would be causing this. I can see the file being attached, I can get some stuff to execute in these files, but not the part that calls Google.

I am just trying to get [this test](https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/3046423?hl=en) to work.

So I have created a custom block with the HTML and attached the .js file in my theme.

#### The JavaScript file

```
   var googletag = googletag || {};
    googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || [];
    (function() {
      var gads = document.createElement("script");
      gads.async = true;
      gads.type = "text/javascript";
      var useSSL = "https:" == document.location.protocol;
      gads.src = (useSSL ? "https:" : "http:") + "//www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js";
      var node =document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
      node.parentNode.insertBefore(gads, node);
     })();

    googletag.cmd.push(function() {
      var adSlot1 = googletag.defineSlot('/6355419/Travel/Europe/France/Paris',[300, 250], "banner1");
      adSlot1.addService(googletag.pubads());
      googletag.enableServices();
    });
```

Comment: First of all, you need to wrap your code around [this function](https://www.drupal.org/node/756722#using-jquery) in order for drupal to recognize it. If it's still doesn't work, I think in Drupal 8 you have to enable jquery, so it loads jquery.min.js on your page.

Comment: Do you have any ideas if I have wrapped them in the the jquery code and it still doesnt work.